# Copying an output of a Python program from Windows command prompt produces faulty data

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

When I copy output of a Python program from the Windows command prompt, wrong values are often produced. They look fine in the terminal, but when I paste them elsewhere (eg. browser, text editor etc.) some data is replaced with random characters. This usually happens when the floating point numbers are involved (eg. see code below):

```
import random

for i in range(0, 500):
    a = random.randint(0, 10) * 1.15
    print(a, end=" ")
```

"random" library is not causing the issue (I think).

This is how the output looks in the console:
[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7vKl.png)

And this is how output looks like as soon as I copy it to VS code:
[Same output in the VS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwCNK.png)

I tried saving output to the .txt file - it looks fine inside the file, but when I copy it elsewhere - the same issue appears.

Comment: @JonSG no, random symbols (eg. "8AFcmXsQttSXuBeYCL9fpa2rn5JrDwwoihMerrwF48V7Ar1EKNTZyGa6G2tMFMhEZNEReroTLe2gPSMQw6VZLSD65AyBqzD8AFcmXsQttSXuBeYCL9fpa2rn5JrDwwoihMerrwF48V7Ar1EKNTZyGa6G2tMFMhEZNEReroTLe2gPSMQw6VZLSD65AyBqzD" appear). Colours are not used in the program.

Comment: Ya, sorry I missed that when I first commented, however I am unable to reproduce. If I run it in powshell, cmd or windows terminal the output I get when copied and passed to an editor like VSC or sublime looks fine

Comment: Update: This can be a Windows 10 issue.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Friedrich In this sort of case I'd say an image is more useful: more representative of the problem, and more likely to reveal clues about the actual problem.